# Can't import merkletools library in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache, cgi

I save successfully executed merkletools operations in normal python scripts. But when working on **CGI** scripts, I cant import merkletools library using `from merkletools import MerkleTools` . Is there any solution for this ?

I am working on apache2 server. apache2 error log is as follows

```
    [Tue Oct 30 17:16:13.309058 2018] [cgi:error] [pid 23964:tid 139710529734400] [client 192.168.2.91:51042] AH01215: Traceback (most recent call last):: /var/www/cgi-bin/file.py, referer: http://192.168.2.91/
    [Tue Oct 30 17:16:13.309199 2018] [cgi:error] [pid 23964:tid 139710529734400] [client 192.168.2.91:51042] AH01215:   File "/var/www/cgi-bin/file.py", line 2, in <module>: /var/www/cgi-bin/file.py, referer: http://192.168.2.91/
    [Tue Oct 30 17:16:13.309254 2018] [cgi:error] [pid 23964:tid 139710529734400] [client 192.168.2.91:51042] AH01215:     : /var/www/cgi-bin/file.py, referer: http://192.168.2.91/
    [Tue Oct 30 17:16:13.309299 2018] [cgi:error] [pid 23964:tid 139710529734400] [client 192.168.2.91:51042] AH01215: from merkletools import MerkleTools: /var/www/cgi-bin/file.py, referer: http://192.168.2.91/
    [Tue Oct 30 17:16:13.309345 2018] [cgi:error] [pid 23964:tid 139710529734400] [client 192.168.2.91:51042] AH01215: ImportError: /var/www/cgi-bin/file.py, referer: http://192.168.2.91/
    [Tue Oct 30 17:16:13.309386 2018] [cgi:error] [pid 23964:tid 139710529734400] [client 192.168.2.91:51042] AH01215: : : /var/www/cgi-bin/file.py, referer: http://192.168.2.91/
    [Tue Oct 30 17:16:13.309428 2018] [cgi:error] [pid 23964:tid 139710529734400] [client 192.168.2.91:51042] AH01215: No module named merkletools: /var/www/cgi-bin/file.py, referer: http://192.168.2.91/
    [Tue Oct 30 17:16:13.309449 2018] [cgi:error] [pid 23964:tid 139710529734400] [client 192.168.2.91:51042] AH01215: : /var/www/cgi-bin/file.py, referer: http://192.168.2.91/
    [Tue Oct 30 17:16:13.311719 2018] [cgi:error] [pid 23964:tid 139710529734400] [client 192.168.2.91:51042] End of script output before headers: file.py, referer: http://192.168.2.91/
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer this links - 
1. https://github.com/Tierion/pymerkletools
2. https://github.com/tierion/merkle-tools

Also check your python version and its dependencies.

Comment: I have already learned these repositories. My problem is with importing the module. Is there anything to take care about for the same if my python code is in the root folder ?

Comment: need to check in more details. It'd be great if you can share some log files related to same and more details how you are executing with environment.

Comment: I have solved the issue. The problem was apache cannot read merkletools module since it is running as a different user. I Installed merkletools library globally. Now its running properly. Your support means a lot to me. Thank you

Comment: Glad you find it useful. :)